# Get 2 users mutual time spent based on onlineTime and offlineTime

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:
[image]

And I calculate the time user has spent based on offlinetime - onlinetime,
but what if I want to know the mutual time 2 users spent on the website,

Let's say:

```
number1: 
onlinetime=2022-10-30 10:25:07, offlinetime=2022-10-30 10:25:30

number2: 
onlinetime=2022-10-30 10:25:08, offlinetime=2022-10-30 10:25:20
```

Now the mutual time they spent together on the website **is 12 seconds**,

how do I query this in MySQL or in PHP?

Comment: Could you clarify whether we should always just compare one set of `onlinetime` and `offlinetime`, or whether we should compare all possible sets for two users in the database?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware All possible sets, any idea or reference?

Comment: OK, I would do this in MySQL, because getting all possible sets and then checking them in PHP would take a lot longer. I will have a try/look.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Interesting... would love to see your approach with MySQL. Take your time!

Comment: Sorry, this problem is more difficult than you would think. I haven't got the time to look into this now. It can be done, but I can't immediately say how. It's an interesting problem though.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no worries man, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/26260) here's the PHP equivalent for comparing one pair of start-end intervals. If you want to expand this for 2 lists of intervals, need to double for loop to sum all pairs. I guess.

```php
function duration($as, $ae, $bs, $be) {
    // a-start, a-end, b-start, b-end
  
    if ($bs > $ae || $as > $be) {
      return 0;
    };
    $os = max($as, $bs);
    $oe = min($ae, $be);
    return $oe - $os;
  }

  $onlinetime = (new DateTime("2022-10-30 10:25:07"))->getTimestamp();
  $offlinetime = (new DateTime("2022-10-30 10:25:30"))->getTimestamp();
  
  
  $onlinetime2 = (new DateTime("2022-10-30 10:25:08"))->getTimestamp();
  $offlinetime2 = (new DateTime("2022-10-30 10:25:20"))->getTimestamp();
  
echo(duration($onlinetime, $offlinetime, $onlinetime2, $offlinetime2));
```

Here's js version:

```js
function duration(as, ae, bs, be) {
  // a-start, a-end, b-start, b-end

  if (bs > ae || as > be) {
    return 0
  }
  var os = Math.max(as, bs)
  var oe = Math.min(ae, be)
  return oe - os
}

var onlinetime = new Date("2022-10-30 10:25:07");
var offlinetime = new Date("2022-10-30 10:25:30");


var onlinetime2 = new Date("2022-10-30 10:25:08");
var offlinetime2 = new Date("2022-10-30 10:25:20");

console.log(duration(onlinetime, offlinetime, onlinetime2, offlinetime2)/1000 + " seconds");
```